Hadoop cannot make a MapReduce operation because is getting hang, waiting for AM container to be allocated
I used my teacher's guide to install and configure Hadoop (it's my first time using it). It says it is for Ubuntu, but it should for all linux distros since it just compiles Hadoop from source. Since I'm using Arch, the I had to modify the java directory from JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 to JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk, and I'm using v. 3.4.0 instead of 3.3.4, but that's it.
I am running Hadoop locally on my laptop, and JPS seems to be working fine:
75761 ResourceManager
75392 SecondaryNameNode
75140 NameNode
75239 DataNode
75990 NodeManager
76270 Jps

But when running this command (MapReduce scripts can be found here):
hadoop jar /home/alberto/Descargas/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.4.0.jar     -files /home/alberto/wordcountPython/mapperWordCount.py,/home/alberto/wordcountPython/reducerWordCount.py     -mapper /home/alberto/wordcountPython/mapperWordCount.py     -reducer /home/alberto/wordcountPython/reducerWordCount.py     -input file:///home/alberto/wordcountPython/prueba.txt     -output salida
this is what I get:
packageJobJar: [/tmp/hadoop-unjar4569006665159328959/] [] /tmp/streamjob5667140313735930625.jar tmpDir=null
2024-06-26 14:11:36,551 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2024-06-26 14:11:36,656 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2024-06-26 14:11:36,891 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/alberto/.staging/job_1719403741005_0002
2024-06-26 14:11:37,643 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2024-06-26 14:11:38,138 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
2024-06-26 14:11:38,246 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1719403741005_0002
2024-06-26 14:11:38,247 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2024-06-26 14:11:38,365 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2024-06-26 14:11:38,365 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2024-06-26 14:11:38,737 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1719403741005_0002
2024-06-26 14:11:38,781 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://archlinux:8088/proxy/application_1719403741005_0002/
2024-06-26 14:11:38,782 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1719403741005_0002

And if I go to the application URL (http://archlinux:8088/proxy/application_1719403741005_0002/) I can see this:

YarnApplicationState:     ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.
Diagnostics:  [mié jun 26 14:11:38 +0200 2024] Application is added to the scheduler and is not yet activated. Skipping AM assignment as cluster resource is empty. Details : AM Partition = <DEFAULT_PARTITION>; AM Resource Request = <memory:2048, vCores:1>; Queue Resource Limit for AM = <memory:0, vCores:0>; User AM Resource Limit of the queue = <memory:0, vCores:0>; Queue AM Resource Usage = <memory:0, vCores:0>;

Screenshot here for more context
I don't know what to do to make it work.
